# Read and print XML with only small changes using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've been looking for a simple way to print an XML from a URL, exactly as it came, with only a few changes. I have this feed:

```
<products>
<product>
<name>Product example</name>
<image>http://example.com</image>
</product>
</products>
```

I want to take this and print it out like this:

```
<products>
<product>
<name>Product example</name>
<image>http://example.com?utm_campaign=changes</image>
</product>
</products>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load an XML file using simplexml_load_file()

Doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php

It permits to create an object from the XML loaded. Just modify what you want on, then use dom_import_simplexml() to transform it into a DOMElement.

Doc : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php

Using DOMElement::saveXml() returning the XML result.

Doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.savexml.php

Don't know if it's the easiest way, but it would work.

Thanks.